# How can I solve $\bar{z}^2+3z+1=0$?

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

I do not manage to solve it as a real equation nor to find a solution with the algebraic form.

Comment: Why not expand the left hand in terms of $x,y$  (where $z=x+iy$)?

Comment: Yeah, I tried. If I put z=x+iy I have

$(\bar z)^2=x^2-2ixy-y^2$

and the equation becomes $x^2-2ixy-y^2+3x+3iy+1=0$

But then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pair the original equation

$\overline z^2+3z+1=0$

with its conjugate which must be simultaneously satisfied:

$z^2+3\overline z+1=0$

From the conjugate equation infer $\overline z=-(z^2+1)/3$.  Substitute into the first equation thus

$(z^2+1)^2/9+3z+1=0$

$z^4+2z^2+27z+10=0$

If you try rational roots to this equation you will fail.  But there is a better way to factor it:  if the equation without conjugation

$z^2+3z+1=0$

has real roots then these also satisfy the complex equation you are trying to solve because then $z=\overline z$.  That works because the discriminant is positive.  So we are sure that $z^2+3z+1$ is a factor of the quartic and we can divide it out to get the factored equation

$(z^2+3z+1)(z^2-3z+10)=0$

Each of these quadratic equations is solved to give the roots

$(-3\pm\sqrt5)/2$

$(3\pm i\sqrt{31})/2$

Answer (score 1):

Put $z=x+iy$ and $\bar z=x-iy$
$$\bar z^2+3z+1=0$$
$$\implies (x-iy)^2 +3(x+iy) +1=0$$
$$\implies (x^2-y^2+3x +1) +i(3y-2xy)=0$$

Now you have two variables (x and y) and two equations. Solve them to get the value of x and y and eventually z.
$$x^2-y^2+3x +1 =0$$
$$3y-2xy=0$$

Comment: Is it correct to say that $3y-2xy=0$ implies $x=3/2$ and then to use the substitution to find the value of $y^2$ ?

Comment: yes, you can always divide an equation by any nonzero quantity. You will get 2 values of y and hence 2 values of z.

Comment: Ok, I solved the exercise. I had to find that the product of the roots of the complex number z is 10. Thank you.

Comment: @vikash you cannot immediately conclude $x=3/2$ because also possibly $y=0$.  Therefore there are more solutions.  See my approach where I factor out the real roots first.

Comment: here, I assumed z is an imaginary number and hence it has some imaginary parts. If we consider z as real number we get 2 more real roots of the equation which is also logical unless it is explicitly stated in the question.